# How to get top,left,right,bottom value using x and y axis value with react-draggable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, position

I am new to react.js just wanna to build some dragging feature but react-draggable is only giving x and y axis.But i need top,left,right,bottom value I don't know how to get that

My try

```
  handleOnDrag(e,data,id){
      // I don't know
        console.log(e,data)

    }
...
      <Draggable onDrag={(e,data) => this.handleOnDrag(e,data,id)}  key={i}  >
                    <p>I am draggable</p>
                                </Draggable>
...
```

Comment: Does data contain the DOM node? If so, get the dimensions off that.

Comment: I tried but not working just wait iI will update the code